# Why is this a bad question?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28443044/4042114). It's clear, simple, and maybe a stupid question, but I think it's valid. What's wrong with it?

One commenter said:

> I downvoted this because it is another "I stare at some code and make assumptions over compiler-work"-question. The only answer to all of these question: Write the most logical and readable code possible, then optimize what you find to be too slow by measurement.

Why? This is just a disrespectful way of saying I need to read a book on how to write a compiler.

Comment: For starters, reading the question, I have *no idea* what you are actually asking.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was about to say the exact same thing. I understand each of the words in the question individually, but when you put them together it's completely incoherent.

Comment: In this case, yes, its bad enough that it gets in the way of us being able to comprehend your question.

Comment: ...comprehended

Answer (score 8):

Let's do a question review!

> Am creating a component class.

Okay, this is a simple grammar mistake, but I'm guessing English isn't your first language (and English is hard), so giving you the benefit of the doubt, I'll mentally insert the pronoun.

This is still really vague. A "component class"? That could be any number of things.

> Some are more properties which are only holding data, others have an manipulation function.

Again, the grammar and structure here makes it hard for a native English speaker to parse. Still, it's coherent.

> Please consider this structure. Properties will have the execution function but empty.

Woah, woah, woah. What? What structure? You followed that with a pretty large block of code. "Properties will have the execution function but be empty"?

Looking at your code, I can figure out what you're trying to say, but it's a little too broad and vague. Be specific! Explicitly saying "`Base` has an `execute` method on it that will be inherited by the component classes; plain old data objects will just leave the `execute` method empty," would be more clear.

> Thought behind my question: Ofcourse another base in between the chain can be created and check it with an identifier.

Wat. I got about half way through this sentence before giving up utterly. "Another base in between the chain"? What's the chain? The inheritance chain? What does creating another base mean? How does the phrase "check it with an identifier" mean *anything at all* in this context?

Some users voted to close your question as "unclear what you're asking," and I'd tend to agree. English is hard, but try to be as specific as possible to at least communicate what you're trying to say. Grammar mistakes are permissible, but after a certain point, things start to lose coherency.

Comment: Plus I *still* have no idea what question the title was trying to ask.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You're right, I barely even thought to look at the question title. I guess I've gotten used to question titles on SO being generally useless.

Comment: Am editting it atm. Indeed English isn't my first language. Learning it by learning to code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you're saying. Why would my wife tell me to shut up when she can loop through my millions? :P